# How to get tablename in hindi

Tags: oracle11g, character-set

I am working with Oracle 11g and my database character set is AL32UTF8.

I am able to store hindi values in a table but I want the tablename in hindi

EXAMPLE:

```
create a table `राकी`
```

column names are `ऋतु,अवधि`

```
value1 गर्मी,सुबह
value2 सर्दी,शाम
```

How can I create this table in Oracle 11g with character set AL32UTF8?

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: @sachinkumar: of course it's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using non-ascii identifiers requires [quoted identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129), so you need to put the table name and every column name between double quotes:

```
create table "राकी" 
(
   "ऋतु" varchar(100), 
   "अवधि" varchar(100)
);
```

Note that once you do that, you are forced to **always** use quoted identifiers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help sir, But quoted identifier have charter limit if the table name is long it is showing error as Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00972: identifier is too long
00972. 00000 -  "identifier is too long"
*Cause:    An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified.
*Action:   Specify at most 30 characters.

Comment: @Sk.mallika: then you have to use a shorter name (or upgrade to Oracle 12.2 where an identifier is allowed to be 128 byte long)

Comment: Thanks again sir,my table name have more than 30 characters.Is their any chance to create a table in Hindi with out quoted identifier.like changing character set...etc

Comment: @Sk.mallika: as I already wrote: the only way to overcome the limit of 30 bytes (not characters) is to upgrade to Oracle 12.2 - but you still need the quotes if you use non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Why character set AL32UTF8 is not supporting non-ascii identifiers? and which type of character set supports the non-ascii identifiers.

Comment: For "why" Oracle does not support this, you have to ask Oracle. I can only show you how to do what you asked for.